# Filter HTML out of JSON object with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, wordpress, angularjs

I'm currectly working on a Wordpress project. But for a nice change I'm working with a JSON API, which only gives me the information I need.

I'm only facing one problem at the moment. The content part in my JSON contains HTML tags, which get printed on the screen, without actually using the HTML tags.

The JSON output looks like this:

```
 [{
"ID": 11,
"title": "test",
"status": "publish",
"type": "page",
"author": {
    "ID": 1,
    "name": "admin",
    "slug": "admin",
    "URL": "",
    "avatar": "http:\/\/0.gravatar.com\/avatar\/401f2b3c91dee8969b193544c3d9a636&d=404&r=G",
    "meta": {
        "links": {
            "self": "http:\/\/geertvandelangenberg.nl\/wp\/wp-json.php\/users\/1",
            "archives": "http:\/\/geertvandelangenberg.nl\/wp\/wp-json.php\/users\/1\/posts"
        }
    }
},
"content": "<p>testtt<\/p>\n", 
}]
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<script src="http://geertvandelangenberg.nl/wp/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function PostsCtrlAjax($scope, $http) {
        $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://geertvandelangenberg.nl/wp/wp-json.php/pages/'}).success(function(data) {
            $scope.posts = data; // response data 
        });
    }
</script>

    <div id="ng-app" ng-ap- ng-controller="PostsCtrlAjax">
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts">
            <h2>
                <a href='{{post.link}}'>{{post.title}}</a>
            </h2>
            <div class="time">
                {{post.date}} - {{post.author.name}}
            </div>
            <p>{{post.content}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Could anyone tell me how I can filter out the HTML tags in the JSON object?

Thanks in advance!

Geert

**EDIT**

Thanks for you comments so far, could anyone please edit this jsbin, I can't seem to manage to get this to work, even with the AngularJS docs. I'm still quite noobish with Angular, but if someone would help me, it'd be much appreciated :)

jsbin.com/oRoqIJEC/1/edit

PS. output does not work on jsbin because of stupid Access-Control-Allow-Origin issues..

Comment: Do you want to escape the tags so it will literally display `<p>testtt</p>` or remove the tags themselves -- or remove the tags *and* their contents?

Comment: Well, the tags could be usefull if they were actually doing something! Only now the tags are just printed on the screen.

Comment: Sounds like you need to compile the HTML from JSON and append

Comment: Try using `<p ng-bind-html="post.content">`

Comment: If using ng-bing-html, you will need to add ngSanatize to your app. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ng-bind-html` will render your HTML.  Don't forget to inject `ngSanitize` into your controller though.

Comment: This is correct. For the docs on -> http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml

Comment: Thanks for you comments so far, could anyone please edit this jsbin, O can't seem to manage to get this to work, even with the AngularJS docs. I'm still quite noobish with Angular, but if someone would help me, it'd be much appreciated :)

http://jsbin.com/oRoqIJEC/1/edit

PS. output does not work on jsbin because of stupid Access-Control-Allow-Origin issues..